# undefined reference to `vtable for ' namespace inheritance undefined reference to `typeinfo for

Tags: c++

I have such error messages while compiling my (simple) code:

```
||=== Build: Release in zad12 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj/Release/Section.o||In function `MyFigures::Section::Section()':|
Section.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for MyFigures::Figure'|
obj/Release/Section.o||In function `MyFigures::Section::Section(Point, Point)':|
Section.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for MyFigures::Figure'|
obj/Release/Section.o||In function `MyFigures::Section::~Section()':|
Section.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for MyFigures::Figure'|
Section.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for MyFigures::Figure'|
obj/Release/Section.o:(.rodata._ZTIN10MyFigures7SectionE[_ZTIN10MyFigures7SectionE]+0x10)||undefined reference to `typeinfo for MyFigures::Figure'|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

And the code:

```
#ifndef _FIGURE_H_
#define _FIGURE_H_

namespace MyFigures
{
class Figure
{
    public:

        Figure(){}
         ~Figure(){}

        virtual void draw();
        virtual void move();
        virtual void scale(double s);
};
}
#endif

#ifndef _Section_H_
#define _Section_H_

#include "figure.h"
#include "point.h"
#include <exception>

namespace MyFigures
{

class Section : public Figure
{
public:
    class badsection : public std::exception
    {
    public:
        const char * what() const throw()
        {
            return "error";
        }
    };

    Section();
    Section(Point start, Point end);
    void draw();
    void move();
    void scale(double s);
    ~Section();

private:

    Point start;
    Point end;
};

}

#endif

#include "section.h"

namespace MyFigures
{

Section::Section()
{
}

Section::Section(Point start, Point end)
{
    if(start == end)
        throw badsection();
}

void Section::draw() {}
void Section::move() {}
void Section::scale(double s) {}
Section::~Section() {}

}

#ifndef _Point_H_
#define _Point_H_

class Point
{
    private:

        double x,y;

    public:

        Point();
        ~Point();
        Point(double xx);
        Point(double xx, double yy);

        Point& operator=(const Point& p);
        bool operator==(const Point& p);

};

#endif

#include "point.h"

Point::Point()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Point::Point(double xx)
{
    x = xx;
    y = 0;
}

Point::Point(double xx=0, double yy=0)
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
}

Point::~Point()
{
}

Point& Point::operator=(const Point& p)
{
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    return *this;
}

bool Point::operator==(const Point& p)
{
    return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
}
```

I tried to make the destructor in `Figure` class as virtual, but no effect (errors remain).

Comment: The vtable is placed where the first virtual function is defined, but you seem to never define the functions from the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you have to define **every** function you declare. That's why the compiler is complaining, you are not defining anything for `draw`, `move` or `scale`.

If you want `Figure` to be a complete abstract class (which I think this is what you are trying to do), you can set those function to `0`, so you don't have to define them, but the derived classes have to implement them.

```
//Now you don't need to implement them
virtual void draw() = 0;
virtual void move() = 0;
virtual void scale(double) = 0;
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much - I completely forgot about this.

Comment: @user2079303 I always get those mixed up, thanks :)